# saving .gif images in external memory android

Tags: android, uri, gif

I have to share GIF images from URL to some other applications using intent, as per my knowledge for sharing them from url I have to save them first in my phone's memory.
I have used GLIDE lib to show them, how could I store them to share? My code so far (not working): It saves only one image from the set of frames of GIF image.

```
  if (mGIFArrayList != null) {
                              //  imageUri = getLocalBitmapUri(imageViewSimple);
                               // shareWithAppChooser(imageUri,"");
                                Glide
                                        .with(mContext)
                                        .load(mGIFArrayList.get(getPosition()).getStrUrl())
                                        .asGif()
                                        .toBytes()
                                        .into(new SimpleTarget<byte[]>() {
                                            @Override public void onResourceReady(final byte[] resource, GlideAnimation<? super byte[]> glideAnimation) {
                                                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                                                    @Override protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                                      //  File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                                                        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "shared_gif_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".gif");
                                                        File dir = file.getParentFile();
                                                        try {
                                                            if (!dir.mkdirs() && (!dir.exists() || !dir.isDirectory())) {
                                                                throw new IOException("Cannot ensure parent directory for file " + file);
                                                            }
                                                            BufferedOutputStream s = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                                                            s.write(resource);
                                                            s.flush();
                                                            s.close();
                                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                                        }
                                                        return null;
                                                    }
                                                }.execute();
                                            }
                                        })
                                ;
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

on the following two lines you determine that the drawable is a `GlideBitmapDrawable`

```
    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    if (drawable instanceof GlideBitmapDrawable) {
```

and then on the following like you cast it to `GifDrawable`:

```
   GifDrawable gifDrawable = ((GifDrawable) imageView.getDrawable());
```

I'm sure it's throwing a `ClassCastException` as GifDrawable and GlideBitmapDrawable are not related.

Unfortunately I don't think you can extract the file from the GifDrawable, because it doesn't work like this.

Probably your best workaround it, is to download the gif file from the `link` to the device storage, and then sharing the file.

Comment: yes you are right .. I tried to download gif to device using glide plz check edit but it download only first image of gif frames

Comment: but you're asking `.asBitmap()`. That is also not a Gif. You probably want to use the `downloadOnly` option. https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/RequestManager.java#L342 which will get u the file directly.

Comment: I realised and changed that to asGIF .. also not working .. let me check downloadOnly ,hope that will work

Comment: @NibhaJain Did it work? How did you achieve sharing using glide?

Comment: @DevKRos: I was able to download Gif and share it..the above code (in my question ) worked